# Fourier Transform in spherical coordinates

Tags: fourier-transform

I have a problem finding the Inverse Fourier transform of the

$$e^{i\bf{k}\cdot\bf{r}}\dfrac{1}{k^2+a^2}$$

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Converting to spherical coordinates in $k$-space and rotating the system so that $\vec r$ aligns with the $k_z$ axis, we have

$$\begin{align}
\int_{-\infty}^\infty\int_{-\infty}^\infty\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{e^{i\vec k\cdot \vec r }}{k^2+a^2}\,dk_x\,dk_y\,dk_z&=\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^\pi \int_0^\infty \frac{e^{ikr\cos(\theta)}}{k^2+a^2}\,k^2\,dk\,\sin(\theta)\,d\theta\,d\phi\\\\
&=2\pi \int_0^\pi \int_0^\infty \frac{e^{ikr\cos(\theta)}}{k^2+a^2}\,k^2\,dk\,\sin(\theta)\,d\theta\\\\
&=2\pi \int_0^\infty \frac{k^2}{k^2+a^2} \int_0^\pi  e^{ikr\cos(\theta)}\sin(\theta)\,d\theta\,dk\,\\\\
&=4\pi \int_0^\infty \frac{k}{k^2+a^2}\left(\frac{\sin(kr)}{r}\right)\,dk
\end{align}$$

The integral over $k$ can be evaluated using, for example, contour integration.  The result is $\displaystyle2\pi ^2\frac{e^{-|a|r}}r$

Can you finish now?

Comment: No it was very helpful. Thank you very much. 
I have a hard time find the same result as one finds in a book i read.
Now I have another term I have to find the Fourier transform.
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2173405/fourier-transform-in-spherical-coordinates
I will be very thankful if you could help me.

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.   -Mark

Comment: Should it not rather be 'so that $\vec{r}$ aligns with the $k_z$-axis'?

Comment: @guillermobcn Yes.  That is correct.